# php insert / update one column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

I want to insert data into department column because it only has Null values so I created Variable called $department grabbing correct data but I don't want to affected the other columns they already have correct data.

```
users

UserID , first name  , last name , department
```

right now not sure what am doing wrong. this is what i have tried.

```
UPDATE Users SET department= '$department'";
```

INSERT INTO Users (department) VALUES ('$department');

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> but I don't want to affected the other columns they already have correct data.

So filter out the rows you don't want to update:

```
UPDATE Users SET department= '$department'" WHERE department IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Users SET department = '$department' WHERE department IS NULL;
```

This query put your correct value on each record that department field is null.